# Angular2 QuickStart refuse to build for release candidate

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to walk through the quickstart for Angular2 now when the release candidate is out. 
However, the typescript compiler throws a lot of errors that I can't figure out.

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

First a lot of lines like this.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(39,88): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(99,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

and then this...
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "tsc"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 tsc: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 tsc script 'tsc'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Development\Angular2RCQuickstart\npm-debug.log

Anyone out there that knows what's wrong?

Comment: in beta releases this was fixed with `///<reference path="node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>` but made typings modular and dropped typings for ES6 so it seems

Answer (score 2):

**Easy dirty fix**

Copy the typings folder from Angular 2 beta 17 into @angular project so `///<reference path="node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>` in your top level component works again

**Clean fix**

You have to manualy install the typings for ES6 promise and ES6 collections with `typings install es6-promise` use the `--ambient` flag for tsd (deprecated) typings.

Comment: I found the file browser.d.ts in the angular2-in-memory-web-api project and added this line instead which made it work. I'm not sure what's the best option. 
`///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api/typings/browser.d.ts"/>`